# Query DynamoDB with a hash key and a range key with Boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am having trouble using AWS Boto3 to query DynamoDB with a hash key and a range key at the same time using the recommend KeyConditionExpression. I have attached an example query:

```python
import boto3
from boto3 import dynamodb
from boto3.session import Session
dynamodb_session = Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY,
              aws_secret_access_key=AWS_PASS,
              region_name=DYNAMODB_REGION)
dynamodb = dynamodb_session.resource('dynamodb')
table=dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)
request = {
    'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
        '#n0': 'hash_key',
        '#n1': 'range_key'
    },
    'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
        ':v0': {'S': MY_HASH_KEY},
        ':v1': {'N': GT_RANGE_KEY}
    },
    'KeyConditionExpression': '(#n0 = :v0) AND (#n1 > :v1)',
    'TableName': TABLE_NAME
}
response = table.query(**request)
```

When I run this against a table with the following scheme:

```
Table Name: TABLE_NAME
Primary Hash Key: hash_key (String)
Primary Range Key: range_key (Number)
```

I get the following error and I cannot understand why:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: >, operand type: M
```

From my understanding the type M would be a map or dictionary type and I am using a type N which is a number type and matches my table scheme for the range key. If someone could explain why this error is happening or I am also open to a different way of accomplishing the same query even if you cannot explain why this error exists.

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong with your code? I'm running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The Boto 3 SDK constructs a Condition Expression for you when you use the Key and Attr functions imported from [boto3.dynamodb.conditions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#dynamodb-conditions):

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('hash_key').eq(hash_value) & Key('range_key').eq(range_key_value)

)
```

Reference: [Step 4: Query and Scan the Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Follow up question about this but would you know if there's a way to batch do that?

Comment: I have a list of hash values. Is there any way I can join a list with boolean `|` using list comprehension? Something along the lines of `'|'.join([Key('hash_key').eq(v) for v in values])`

Comment: @falsePockets Just tried it, it gives "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: KeyConditionExpressions must only contain one condition per key"

Comment: @falsePockets exactly you cannot search for a range in a Dynamo Key you must use FilterExpresion
``` python
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('hash_key').eq(hash_value) 
    FilterConditionExpression=Key('range_key').gr(range_key_value)
) 
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding this solution as the accepted answer did not address why the query used did not work.

TLDR: Using query on a `Table` resource in boto3 has subtle differences as opposed to using `client.query(...)` and requires a different syntax.

The syntax is valid for a query on a client, but not on a Table. The `ExpressionAttributeValues` on a table do not require you to specify the data type. Also if you are executing a query on a `Table` resource you do not have to specify the `TableName` again.

Working solution:

```py
from boto3.session import Session

dynamodb_session = Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=AWS_PASS,region_name=DYNAMODB_REGION)

dynamodb = dynamodb_session.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)

request = {
    'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
        '#n0': 'hash_key',
        '#n1': 'range_key'
    },
    'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
        ':v0': MY_HASH_KEY,
        ':v1': GT_RANGE_KEY
    },
    'KeyConditionExpression': '(#n0 = :v0) AND (#n1 > :v1)',
}
response = table.query(**request)
```

I am the author of a package called [botoful](https://www.botoful.com) which might be useful to avoid dealing with these complexities. The code using botoful will be as follows:

```py
import boto3
from botoful import Query

client = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_PASS,
    region_name=DYNAMODB_REGION
).client('dynamodb')

results = (
    Query(TABLE_NAME)
        .key(hash_key=MY_HASH_KEY, range_key__gt=GT_RANGE_KEY)
        .execute(client)
)

print(results.items)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at using `boto3` to query Dynamodb with composite keys in 2023 this is the first result from google.

To return a single record, the easiest way is to just pass the hash_key and range_key as a dictionary to the `key` argument on the `get_item` method.

e.g.

```py
from boto3 import resource

dynamodb_table = resource("dynamodb", region_name="eu-west-1").Table("your_table_name")
dynamodb_table.get_item(Key={"hash_key_name": "value", "range_key_name": "value"})
```

For returning more than one object, I recommend using the query method and using the `KeyConditionExpression` argument. Then using the arguments from the `boto3.dynamodb.conditions` class to build your query. The example below giving the same results as the example above.

For example

```py
from boto3 import resource
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

dynamodb_table = resource("dynamodb", region_name="eu-west-1").Table("your_table_name")
dynamodb_table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key("hash_key_name").eq("value")
    & Key("range_key_name").eq("value")
)
```

The key difference is `get_item`, results are stored in "Item" key, while `query` results are in `Items` and are stored as a list